# What are the options of a space enthusiast regarding visiting Plesetsk?

Tags: russia, tourism

Last year I was in Murmansk and fell in love with the far north of Russia. I'm planning another trip somewhere towards Karelia, northern Ural or such... and being a space enthusiast I'm quite tempted to try visiting the Plesetsk cosmodrome. Of course visiting places like that usually isn't nearly as easy as a tourist trip to Kennedy Space Center - military zones, permits required with application submitted a good time ahead of the planned visit, maybe an authorized guide or such. But then maybe there is a guided tours firm that manages this all, or maybe there's just a hill nearby where anyone can come no questions asked and watch a launch (providing there's a launch schedule for Plesetsk available... is there?)

So, what are my options?

Comment: There are R-7 launches planned for 2019 on Plesetsk:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_R-7_launches_(2015%E2%80%932019) . 
There may also be other type of launches, this list is only for R-7.
No idea if there's a good hill to watch them :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mirny (site of Plesetsk Cosmodrome) is a closed town.

At the moment, tours are only for Russian schoolchildren.

Comment: I know often there are ways to visit closed towns and restricted zones. They are sometimes rather expensive and often complex or requiring the right contacts, but my mother visited the Titovka waterfalls after a short talk with the officers at the checkpoint, I rode a bus through the restricted zone around Severomorsk-3 no questions asked, and even got an invitation to visit Snezhnogorsk, a closed town, with a promise of a permit  (didn't pan out though) so... maybe there are ways to see Mirny too.

Comment: You can visit Plesetsk city. But Mirny settlement  - special conditions are necessary. the closed city of Mirny, which can be visited only with special permites. I think this is unlikely for foreigners. Especially for US and EU citizens.

Comment: Excursion program is designed for middle and high school students.
- Only citizens of the Russian Federation.

"Программа рассчитана на учащихся средних и старших классов
— только граждан РФ." https://anoarvt.ru/tours/platnye-ekskursii/ekskursionnaya-programma-plesetsk-severodvinsk/